# How to read xml data by passing my headers to the URL ..error : `<Response 400>`

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I am new to this type of task and how to use request module in python

I have a URL which as xml data in it and this URL can only be accessed by passing headers to it

**My code :**

```
import requests
url = '....'  # not mentioning its private cannot be shared 
header_details =
{
"d" : "a45",
"cot" : "yuui",
"pid" : "1345",
"Host" : "abc.vmp.com",
"Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}

my_data = requests.get(url,header=header_details)
print(my_data)
```

Required your guidance on this ... the above code throws me `<Response 400>`

The output will be returned which is going to be xml data. That I need to write to some file `-> abc.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, the parameter is called `headers` (plural):

```py
my_data = requests.get(url, headers=header_details)
```

Comment: Can you tell me when to use POST and GET with request and its mandatory that my headers should be passed with my url to get data

Comment: Typically, you use `GET` to get data from the server and `POST` to send data to the server. In this case you do not seem to be sending any data so I assume you want to use get (again depends on the api you are using)